# How to create a factory method in C++ that allows one to polymorphically return different types?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, factory

I have a base type:

```
class Foo{
public:
int height;
int weight;

void jump();

}
```

I have a descendant:

```
class Bar : public Foo{
  //Has a different implementation of jump();
}
```

I have a factory that returns a kind of Foo;

```
static Foo createTheRightThing(int type){
  if (type == 0){
    return Foo();
  }
  else if (type ==1){
    return Bar();
  } 
}
```

The method that calls `createTheRightThing` looks like this:

```
void boo {
   Foo someFoo = FactoryClass::createTheRightThing(1); //Just using 1 to illustrate the problem.

}
```

The problem:

someFoo is always a `Foo`, and never a `Bar`, even when I pass 1 in. When I pass 1 in, I can see that the correct else block is entered, and the factory does indeed return a `Bar`.
The member variables, match those set by the factory when creating the Bar.
   If I call `someFoo.jump()`, it is always the `jump()` in a Foo. It never calls the `jump()` in `Bar`.

**What am I doing incorrectly ? How do I fix it ?** I understand polymorphism in Java, Objective-c, but don't have much experience in C++. Is this problem because I am not creating a new object and returning a pointer ?

Comment: you have to use pointer or reference to keep polymorphism!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By returning the objects by value from the factory function, you're [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c) them so that they'll always be the factory function's return type, which is `Foo`. For polymorphism to work, you need to return a pointer (reference would work too, but pointer is more appropriate in this case) to the object you create. You should change the factory function to

```
static std::unique_ptr<Foo> createTheRightThing(int type){
  if (type == 0){
    return std::unique_ptr<Foo>(new Foo());
  }
  else if (type ==1){
    return std::unique_ptr<Foo>(new Bar());
  } 

  // and maybe add this, or throw an exception
  return std::unique_ptr<Foo>();
}
```

---

In order for this to work correctly, you'll also need the following changes - `Foo::jump` should be `virtual`, as should the destructor of `Foo`

```
class Foo{
public:
  int height;
  int weight;

  virtual void jump();
  virtual ~Foo() = default;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

1. You have slicing problem. [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c)
2. `jump` need to be `virtual` function for polymorphism. Which means you have to think about [rule of three/five/zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) [Rule-of-Three becomes Rule-of-Five with C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11)

So instead of returning `Foo`, you need to return a reference/pointer/smart poitner type.

```
class Foo{
public:
int height;
int weight;

virtual void jump();
virtual ~Foo() {}

}

class Bar : public Foo{
  //Has a different implementation of jump();
    void jump() override;
}

static std::shared_ptr<Foo> createTheRightThing(int type){ // better use enum type
  if (type == 0){ // better use switch case
    return std::make_shared<Foo>();
  }
  else if (type ==1){
    return std::make_shared<Bar>();
  } 
  // you need to return something here or have an assertion 
  // or (not recommended) throw exception
  return {}; // nullptr / std::shared_ptr<Foo>()
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't return a shared pointer though. There is nothing in the problem that suggests shared ownership is required.

Comment: shared pointer is just a quick solution that works for most of the cases. of cause unique pointer can be more optimal depends on the specific requirement.

Comment: without more details, you can't say this is wrong. but I agree unique pointer should be the default choice. and Praetorian already provide one so I won't change my answer.